# Find the most expensive order

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I'm trying to find the most expensive order within my table, and I've achieved this, but I'd like to know how to just return this one particular row. Right now it turns all rows with the most expensive order at the top. I'm not quite sure how to return just the most expensive order. I've grouped the orders by the order number (`order_numb`). I've tried using `IN` and a self join but I can't seem to get it to work.

#### My table

[image]

#### My current query that returns the correct result, just it returns all rows

```
SELECT order_numb, sum(cost_each) as totalSum
FROM order_lines 
GROUP BY order_numb
ORDER BY totalSum DESC
```

#### What I'm trying to achieve

I'm trying to retrieve the most expensive order by itself.

I'm using Oracle as my database.

Comment: Should you not be summing cost_line? Your query probably doesn't work for order lines with a quantity > 1....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROWNUM` to filter the first row (most expensive order) of the result set:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT order_numb, sum(cost_each) as totalSum 
  FROM order_lines 
  GROUP BY order_numb 
  ORDER BY totalSum DESC
) t
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```